# NSDictionary - Objective-C code in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c

Is it possible to use `NSDictionary` inside ***C++*** class ? I know, I can use ***Objective-C*** classes inside ***C++*** (http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++), but for `NSDictionary`, I need header... but if I do `#import`, it failed to compile.

PS: I know, I shouldnt mix ***Objective-C(++)*** and ***C++***, but I am writing multiplatform OpenGL app and for EAGL initialization one of input parametrs is `NSDictionary`. I could init OpenGL in ***Objective-C***, but it would break my OOP design.

Comment: Did you compile your file as Objective-C++? The quickest way to make sure is to use the file extension .mm. There should be no problem with the #import so what was the error?

Comment: I am compiling it as *.cpp and I am getting erros from objcruntime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure compile the C++ class as Objective-C++ (.mm extension) and you will have no problems.  The only problem I've had doing this is the fact that you can't define the Objective-C++ type inside the C++ header.  So instead I use a void* and cast it to void* using a

```
pVoidDict = (__bridge_retained void*)[NSDictionary dictionary];
```

You will need to perform a bridged cast to use it:

```
unsigned int dictCount = [(__bridge NSDictionary*)pVoidDict count];
```

The only problem is you must remember to release it at the end.  You can do this by casting it back to an NSDictionary as follows:

```
NSDictionary* dict = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)pVoidDict;
```

This will return it to ARC control and when the destructor exits it will be added to the autorelease pool as per standard ARC rules.

Its not particularly nice to look at but I use this quite a bit in a cross-platform library so that I can wrap Objective-C objects with C++ classes.

Comment: is it possible to use it other way ? Having Objective-C++ in *.cpp file ?

Comment: @MartinPerry: While I say its not possible it IS possible to set XCode to compile a file as Objective-C++ but you are still compiling as ObjC++...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Objective-C or change to Objective-C file (.mm) to compile whatsoever, you can stay in C++ completely. The naming changes however. Refer to CFDictionaryCreate and related functions instead.

Comment: Do you mean "Objective-C++ file (.mm)"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thanks

Comment: Then you should edit your answer to reflect that.